# A program that creates another program

Tags: c#, .net

I need to create a program that creates another program but not a compiler though.

For example,

I write a program that accepts a string input from the user. Let's say user enter "Pluto". This program should then create a separate .exe that says "Hello Pluto" when executed.

How can I do this? If you could give example in C# and Windows Forms, it's better.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show us what you've gotten done on this homework assignment so far?

Comment: Looks very much like a code-it-for-me question...

Comment: I wanted to put "this isn't homework", but i thought you guys would give me the benefit of the doubt. I'm already 27 year old. It isn't "code it for me" question. The problem I face is really much bigger, but I reduce the problem to the simple question above.

Comment: Programs creating other programs? That's an abomination!

Comment: I think you meant to say, "pervert" (qouting the 2nd ep of star wars). "Machines making machines, how pervert" - C3PO. But it's really not. There's actually folks within the AI community who build systems through generative algorithm that spawns new programs and over time these programs evolve to solve the problem more accuratly. I know of an example where a robot learnd to stand on it's own and then also retain balance if shoved through the use of such an approach. I do not know if this is related to AI or not, but there's a sound reasoning behind all this.

Comment: The word is 'perverse' not 'pervert'.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Basically that *is* a compiler - just for a particularly simple language.

If you can express the final program in C#, the easiest solution is probably to use CSharpCodeProvider. That's what I do for Snippy, a little tool to help run code snippets easily for C# in Depth. The source code to Snippy is [on the C# in Depth web site](http://csharpindepth.com/Downloads.aspx) and can give you an idea of what you might do - basically you'd just want it to write the executable to a file instead of building it in memory.

Alternatively, look at the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx)  which have an example generating an executable.

Comment: upvoted just for the sake of it. if you look over the front page, somebody is just downvoting everything he sees.

Comment: something downvotes everything. Look at the question-list. Many good questions are downvoted. Please stop that bot!

Answer (score 11):

The classes you are looking for are in the `Microsoft.CSharp` namespace

```
CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
ICodeCompiler icc = codeProvider.CreateCompiler();
System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
parameters.OutputAssembly = Output;
CompilerResults results = icc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters,SourceString);
```

(from [microsoft support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655) found by using google - taking less than 20 sec)

Comment: People downvoting proper answers makes me want to downvote those downvoters.

Comment: Please don't use patronizing text in the answer regarding google. The whole point of stackoverflow.com is to not use google and have a coding reference here. Otherwise why don't we all just use google?

Comment: Because certain things can't really be found by using google, because they are too specific to be found. In this case though, it was really easy to find. Now, if you have a question concerning something you've found (and appear to be spend thoughts on it) I don't have a problem with it.

Answer (score 3):

Tentatively, you can also achive this throught he use of things in the System.Reflection.Emit namespace and I believe it's possible to provide the implementation of a method through the use of LINQ expression trees. Which is kind of neat:

```
var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("TestAssembly"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
var mod = assembly.DefineDynamicModule("TestModule");
var type = mod.DefineType("TestType");
var method = type.DefineMethod("Increment", MethodAttributes.Public, typeof(int), Type.EmptyTypes);
Expression<Func<int, int>> inc = (a) => a + 1; // this is cool
inc.CompileToMethod(method);
```

It might look a bit daunting at first, but it's really cool stuff, and you let the compiler generate the hard stuff, the method implementation. But you can't really create fields like this, that's gonna require some IL. Which is great fun but really tedious work.

## DISCLAIMER:

I haven't tried to run the above code. But I know it goes something like that, it's been a while since I've done something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use Reflection.Emit.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ffc3x75.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/DynamicCodeGeneration2.aspx

How to build a HelloWorld.exe using Reflection.Emit (it's less than half-page of code):
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140504194145/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joelpob/archive/2004/01/21/61411.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to create (in advance) a really short simple program that reads a resource from itself and prints it.  Then your application needs only to place that program binary on disk somewhere and call the [UpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648049.aspx) function to change the string.  .NET also has resource support, but I don't know of any function that directly corresponds to UpdateResource.